# how to create labels for each String from a responsed set of Strings? javascript

Tags: javascript, string, foreach, fetch, label

I've got a response from api `["string1","string2","string3"]` etc. and want to create labels with text of those strings.

```
fetch(url).then(text => text.forEach(createLabel));

function createLabel (strings){
        const label = document.createElement('label');
        label.append(document.createTextNode(strings));
        document.getElementById('all-strings').appendChild(label);
    }
```

Above code gives no results beside info that text.forEach is not a function.

Anyone?

Comment: then `text` might not be an `array`

Comment: console.log(text)

Comment: `fetch(url).then(res => res.json()).then(text => text.forEach(createLabel));` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: `text` is a `response` I get -> so it is `["string1","string2","string3"]` etc. It's just a set of Strings, but I cannot do anything with it.